# How can I get movie by id

Tags: angular

I want to get tmdb json data by id to my movie-detail component html but "this value was evaluated upon first expanding it may have changed since then" error

Here is my code

**Movie service**

```
getMovieById(movieId: string): Observable<Movie>{
alert(movieId);
return this.httpClient.get<Movie>(this.path + "results?id=" + movieId);
}
```

**Movie-Detail Component**

```
movies!: Movie;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params=>{
     this.getMovieById(params["movieId"])
    })
  }
getMovieById(movieId: any){
this.movieService.getMovieById(movieId).subscribe(movies=>{
this.movies=data;
})
}
```

**Component HTML**

```
<p><span>{{movie.title}}</span></p>
```

Comment: Could you move the contents of `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit` ?

Comment: I'm new Angular Js so unfortunately didn't understand you , Can you explain how can do it

Comment: I realized is that your subscribe is attributing to movies the variable data who doesn't exist in your code. Another thing that you can try is to initialize the variable movies.

Comment: @GabrielSereno Actually I can write data to console.log but doesn't work on html file

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you are calling an async function in ngOnInit and changing some value (before the page load), so what you can do is like this:

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params=>{
        this.getMovieById(params["movieId"])
       })
    })
  }
```

By doing it, your code is informing Angular that is not necessary to wait for this function to load the page and fill the variable to show it in the HTML

Maybe you will need to do this also:

```html
<p><span>{{movie?.title}}</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi looking code wise looks perfect

Can you provide

1. your route configuration weather it is expecting parameter or not.
2. Response from api

Probably the assignment to the variable is a problem.

And also can you create a sample in plunkr or any other place for more clear understanding.